# How to do something if JS file is blocked

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, adblock

I'm setting up Google Conversion Tracking for a customer and Google wants me to use onclick:

```
<a onclick="return gtag_report_conversion('http://example.com/your-link');" href="http://example.com/your-link">Link text</a>
```

The problem here is if a user is using ad blocker the Google JavaScript file is not loaded and `gtag_report_conversion` can't be used because it's not defined. Unfortunately it results in the anchor tag not working at all and it won't redirect the user anywhere.

My solution for this would be to print the anchor tag with the "onclick" attribute if the JS file is loaded and if it's not loaded then just print an anchor tag without the "onclick" attribute. But how can I detect if the JS file was loaded or not?

**EDIT:** actually `gtag_report_conversion` is defined locally so I would need to check something else. Is there any way to check if external script has loaded?

Comment: you can check for the presence of `gtag_report_conversion` function by just using `typeof`. If it is `"undefined"`  then you know it :-)

Comment: My bad. Actually `gtag_report_conversion` is defined locally. The file I'm loading which gets blocked is [this](https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
try{gtag_report_conversion('http://example.com/your-link')}catch(err){}
```